# Why OpenBazaar is legal and Silk Road was busted?

Tags: criminal-law, internet, international

I don't get it. Why OpenBazaar is considered legal and LE is ok with OB2, but Silk Road was the devil inside. Is it due the the ways it did marketing.

Comment: good info. Do you have other input ? Thx

Comment: You'll need other question for other input. The one you asked has already been answered.